# Keep menu item active after clicking on link on current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, I'm trying to add the class `active` to the current menu item. I succeeded by using the following jQuery code.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var path = window.location.href;
        $('#nav-main li a').each(function() {
            if (this.href === path) {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    });
```

My navigation bar looks like this:

```
    <ul id="nav-main">
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/brands">Brands</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/users">Users</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/employees">Employees</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Which has the following CSS:

```
    ul#nav-main {
        width: 1050px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        color: #fff;
    }
    ul#nav-main li {
        margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 17px;
    }
    ul#nav-main li a {
        padding: 0 15px;
        line-height: 2.692307692;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #fff;
    }
    ul#nav-main li a:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
    ul#nav-main li a.active {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }
```

Now, when I click on 'Users' I go to `/users` and the jQuery code successfully adds the `active` class so that 'Users' is shown as the current menu item in the navigation bar. However, when I click on a link on the 'Users' page which leads to, for example, `/users/view/12345` (in which `12345` is the ID of a user), the 'Users' page isn't shown as the current menu item anymore.

I think this has to do with the fact that the jQuery code only looks to `nav-main li a` and not to other `a`'s at the page. Is there something I could add to my jQuery code to make this work?

Comment: I think it depends on this `if (this.href === path)` When you are in `/users/view/12345` there's no more identity.
But i'm honest, i'm not totally sure, javascript it's not my best.
No wait, of course your code works only if you click on a link in `nav-main li`. You defined jquery acting in this way.

Comment: I've been trying to think of and search for a workaround for both of those facts, but wasn't able to think of or find something to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
var path = window.location.href;
```

to this:

```
var path = "/" + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

`pathname` retrieves everything after (and including) the first slash. `split` will break the string into a list of strings based on a defined separator (`'/'`), and we are going to choose the item with an index of 1.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! But when I change it into what you said, jQuery doesn't add the `active` class to anything anymore. By the way, would your code still work if the website isn't in the root directory, but in a subdirectory?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console? Pathname will retrieve everything after the domain, so for example if your site is `http://test.com/users/view/12345` the code I posted will retrieve `/users`. If your site is nested further you will just have to specify the correct index depending on the number of subdirectories you have. For example if your site was at `http://test.com/mywebsite/something/users/view/12345` you would choose an index of 3 instead of 1.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. I changed the 1 to 3 and found out I had to change your piece of code to this: `var path = "http://domain.com/dir_one/dir_two/" + window.location.pathname.split('/')[3];`. That solved the problem! Although it feels a bit like a hack, as this has to be changed everytime the software I'm writing is being used on another server in another directory.

Comment: What you did was essentially what I described in my last comment, just backwards. I don't think there is really any way around it if you change directories, you are going to have to change which part of the url you are pointing to.

Comment: That's true. The most important part is that I got it working, thanks to you. I might think of a workaround to let the software be able to run in any directory, without the need to edit that line over and over again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. Worked for me. Found it somewhere on the net, but don't remember the source.

```
var i = document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/");
var current = document.location.href.substr(i+1);

    $("#nav-main a").removeClass('active');

    $("#nav-main a[href^='"+current+"']").each(function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: I like the idea, but it's not working in this scenario. I'll save the code so that I can use it when I need it. Thanks!