# How to make <li> remain highlighted when redirected to new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

I'm trying to make call a navigation bar(navbar.html) in to my index.html. Navbar.html has its own css and inside navbar.html is a script that changes the class of `<li>` when `<a>` is pressed.

I have managed to make the `<li>` to change highlight but when I press the `<a>` does not remain highlighted on the new page.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <!--NAVIAGTION BAR-->
    <div id="navbar-placeholder">


    </div>


    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#navbar-placeholder").load("Files/navbar.html");
        });
    </script>
    <!--END OF NAVIGATION BAR-->
</body></html>
```

navbar.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<div class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li class=""><a href="work.html">Work</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".navigation li").click(function() {
            $(".navigation li").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });

</script>
```

navbar.css

```
.navigation{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:#262126;
    text-align: center;
}

.navigation ul{
    margin: 0;
}
.navigation li{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 30px;
    margin: 10px 5px 0px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.navigation a{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.navigation li:hover{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.navigation li:hover a{
    color: black;
}

.navigation li.active{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.navigation li.active a{
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: If the page get's reloaded then have a look at localStorage.

Comment: You want to parse the url and then find appropriate `href` when new page loads. Easy to research how to parse the url. No point changing the class in current page when link is clicked unless it is a single page app

Comment: Try using the query operator `?` or the anchor `#` in the url. And then as @charlietfl said, parse the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is backwards.  Adding the class when click occurs is pointless since you are immediately leaving that page

When each page loads match the current `location.href` to the links and add class then.

```
var $navItems = $(".navigation li").removeClass("active"); 

$navItems.filter(function(){
  return $(this).find('a').prop('href') === location.href;
}).addClass("active");
```

Comment: dont forget to strip the site URL when doing this or it won't match.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie not sure what you mean. The `href` *property* of an `<a>` element is the full url .... is different than the attribute if the attribute is relative url

Comment: You just opend my eyes! Thank you!

Comment: >< yup, ignore me, blonde moment, you got a plus one from me anyway :-P hehe.

Comment: tfl, after googling 4 seconds I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21032480/keep-menu-item-active-after-clicking-on-link-on-current-page) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335936/jquery-keep-active-menu-item-highlighted) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40137260/how-to-keep-nav-menu-highlighted-after-click-using-js-in-sidebar) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438021/javascript-needed-to-keep-active-page-link-highlighted-html5-css) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060467/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url) and gazillion ohers..

Comment: `$('[href*="'+location.href+'"]')` might be useful not only for NAV but for breadcrumb and other silly tiny stuff

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan but `location.href` is absolute url and attribute is not, it is relative